# Can't authenticate REST API with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, flask

I am bulding an app with an AngularJS frontend and a Flask REST API for the backend.

I am trying to authenticate a resource using AngularJS `$http`. My Flask backend is very simple and setup with [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/) decorator to handle the CORS.

My basic view code in Flask looks like:

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    # for now, I just want to see the correct credentials are present
    print 'credentials: %s %s' % (username, password)
    return True

@app.route('/login')
@cross_origin('http:/localhost')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return jsonify({'auth': str(request.authorization)})
```

This works in my local dev environment, so that when I do

```
curl -u myusername:mypassword http://127.0.0.1:5000/login
```

I get the expected result:

```
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'myusername'
> GET /login HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic am9objpoZWxsbw==
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> Accept: */*
> 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 20
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, OPTIONS, GET
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 21600
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
< Vary: Origin
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.1 Python/2.7.3
< Date: Mon, 09 Mar 2015 17:37:27 GMT
{
  "auth": "{'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'mypass'}"
  * Closing connection #0
}
```

In my AngularJS app I want to do the same, so I have an authentication service:

```
myApp

  .service('AuthService', function ($http, $rootScope, $state) {
    return {
      login: function (credentials) {
        console.log('credentials', credentials); // credentials are correct
        return $http
          .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', credentials)
          .then(function (result) {
            // do something
            console.log('result', result);
          });
        },
        ...
     }
  })
```

I also configure `$http`:

```
// CORS
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

When I examine the request details when using `curl` I can clearly see the username and password are passed. However, when using AngularJS the `request.authorization` object in Flask is empty, meaning there are no credentials or they are in the wrong place.

How do I pass the credentials correctly in AngularJS?

Comment: maybe change from http://127.0.0.1:5000/login to just /login. i.e.
$http.get('/login', credentials).then(.......

Comment: No, the url is fine. I can test without the server auth and I get the expected results (response=200 + payload).

Comment: Looks like you aren't setting the authorization header. Usually this is done in an interceptor so that your services don't need to know about it.

Comment: You can try something like this $http({method : 'POST', url : '/login', data : credentials}). BTW passing credentials should be done in POST requests (best practice I guess :) )

Comment: So the authrorization header can be set with: `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization`. Should it contain both the username and password?

Comment: I don't believe the request method is the issue here, but I was under the impression if I am requesting a resource from a RESTful API the correct method is `GET`, with or without Authentication.

Comment: On the client side I get: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5000/login. Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. `, but from the curl response I can clearly see that `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is indeed set to true when the response is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'
```

Comment: I think you are advocating constructing the Authorization header on the fly and adding the password. This doesn't seem like a good solution, and it doesn't solve the problem. Why do you consider this a good answer? Which docs?

Comment: @DarwinTech I just meant to point out that you need an Authorization header with your credentials base64 encoded. I don't know Angular very well, but it appears to me you could make it part of your default config. But, there must also be a way to send the header at run time. The doc I referenced was https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

I apologize for being brief in my original post. A down vote would have worked just fine.

Comment: This part does seem to be part of the issue. Do I need to be encoding my credentials as base64 before the request is made.